# facebook, twitter, youtube app creation and api integration help required... just a small answer required

Tags: facebook, twitter, youtube

I am working on PHP application which will be shipped to many users for their own.

App needs to integrate

Facebook api for auto post their web articles to their fb profile/page.
Twitter api for same purpose as above and to search for tweets/users.
Youtube api to upload videos to their user account.

I already have completed the software, Right now software has api settings menu for each of them. Where user create their own app on respective platform and setup app id/secrets etc... IT works fine...

But I am looking for a way where, we use our own app codes, and user only has to click on button which redirect them to their platform and they can allow access to our app. So they dont have to go through their own app creation.

Just like how login with social media things work...

I know thats possible and my question is not about how to do this...

My question is about IF I do that, will that create any App usage limitation issues for users ? For example, if I create my own Youtube app settings from http://console.developers.google.com/ and all users just authorise my app to their account, will it create any issues if all users (may be 2000 users) uploads upto 5 videos per day ? Will the usage limit counted per application or per user access assigned ?

I need the answer for facebook/twitter and youtube. I know some one how has already done this can answer this quickly and easily...

Thanks for reading my question...

Comment: _“Will the usage limit counted per application or per user access assigned ?”_ – that depends (at least for Facebook) on what kind of access token you will be using. If you are making requests using the user’s own access tokens, then the requests will be counted on a per-user basis, and you should be quite safe in regard to the numbers you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I believe that it will ofcourse use user's access tocken as he is going to authenticate my app with his fb login and allowing me to use his facebook account ? correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: Can any one please help me on this ?